# Why .class is not working for generic types?

Tags: java, class, templates, compilation

The construct

```
Class c = Set<Object>.class;
```

does not compile in Java, while

```
Class c = Set.class;
```

compiles well.

Why?

Comment: Try googling `java type erasure`. You're not by any means the first to ask this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `<Object>` part is "erased" from the type in Java (i.e. the class of `Set<String>` and `Set<Object>` is exactly the same).